# Not able to compile using absolute reference to classpath java

Tags: java

I have created sample java program and trying it compile using the -cp option..

Here is the folder structured

[image]

The javapackage is located under c:/

When I point the directory correctly and compile it , it works fine.. but it does not work when I use the -cp option...

[image]

Comment: The classpath option is to find classes, not source code files. You still have to specifiy the full path to your source file.

Comment: What for to use command line if there is IDE?